# Is there a scoped environment fot the language R beyond the environment function attach to work with data.frames?

Tags: r, expression, scoped

I've a larger script in the programming language R and work with tables. I've a table `base.tab`

```
  ID      LAT      LON ALT.ORTHO TYPE TYPE.ID
1  1 53.75447 12.51539   46.5555 LINE       1
2 10 53.75452 12.51565   46.5445 LINE       1
3 11 53.75452 12.51567   46.5365 LINE       1
4 12 53.75453 12.51570   46.5715 LINE       1
5 13 53.75453 12.51573   46.5785 LINE       1
6 14 53.75454 12.51576   46.6885 LINE       1
```

and want to shorten some expressions without using `attach` or `subset`. Instead of writing

```
base.tab.epos <-
     base.tab[(base.tab$TYPE == 'LINE') |
              (base.tab$TYPE == 'RAND'),  ]
```

I want to use something in a scoped context like:

```
with(base.tab) do { 
    base.tab.epos <-
         base.tab[(TYPE == 'LINE') |
                  (TYPE == 'RAND'),  ] 
}
```

Is there an expression in the programming language R to do that?

Comment: You can use `with`/`within` : `base.tab.epos <- with(base.tab, base.tab[TYPE == 'LINE' |TYPE == 'RAND',  ]) `

Comment: Have a look at package data.table. It allows using `base.tab.epos <- base.tab[(TYPE == 'LINE') | (TYPE == 'RAND')]` without needing `with`. But please read the package vignettes first.

Comment: Why the artificial requirement not to use `subset` since `subset` does exactly what you want: `subset(base.tab, TYPE %in% c("LINE", "RAND"))`

Comment: @Grothendieck subset is fine but it covers only the filter aspect. But if you go to the diagram production (`plot, point, lines, text..`) you have the long column `table.name$column.name` annotation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has `with`/`within` function which can achieve that.

```
base.tab.epos <- base.tab[with(base.tab, TYPE == 'LINE' | TYPE == 'RAND'), ]
```

Apart from that you can also have a look at `dplyr` which will allow you to refer to column names without using `data$` every time.

```
library(dplyr)
base.tab.epos <- base.tab %>% filter(TYPE == 'LINE' | TYPE == 'RAND')
```